# redis-master slave setup failing

Tags: redis

I have started server with port 6001 as master with persistence aof turned off,slave with port 6002 as master of 6001.However on startup of slave i am getting below error in infinite loop also note able to find any error logs of the same..

```
Slave infinite loop logs : 

[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:28.499 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:28.500 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:28.500 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6002
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:28.501 * Connecting to MASTER localhost:6001
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:28.513 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:29.513 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:29.513 # Sending command to master in replication handshake: -Writing to master: Unknown error
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:29.516 * Connecting to MASTER localhost:6001
[5556] 20 Aug 21:34:29.517 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
```

Comment: Also when I run role command on slave it gives following output.::
    
    
    localhost:6002> role
    1) "slave"
    2) "localhost"
    3) (integer) 6001
    4) "connecting"
    5) (integer) -1

Comment: can you please tell me from where you have captured these errors?

Comment: On the command line of slave redis engine startup

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved,redis.conf contained 127.0.0.1 as bind value,and from slave redis.conf file ,I had SLAVE OF localhost .Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 resolved the issue